# How to bind a GridColumn to the index value of an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress

I have a DevExpress GridControl that uses an ObservableCollection of type Student as its ItemsSource.

My GridControl has four columns

```
Name
ID
Favorite Subject
GPA
```

Name, Favorite Subject, and GPA are properties of a Student, so they are accurately binding.

The issue is, I do not want to have a property for ID for a Student. I want to set the ID to be  1 + the index of the Student instance in the ObservableCollection of Students hosting the GridControl.

So if I had three Students the ID column will read as

```
1
2
3
```

I suspect I will need an ObservableCollection of type Ints in my View Model but I am unable to use a different ItemsSource for the ID Column. I can only reference the Parent ItemsSource of the GridControl. Since the ItemsSource is an ObservableCollection of type Student and ID is not a property of Student, I can't seem to set the column to the appropriate values (mentioned above).

```
<dxg:GridControl Style="{StaticResource StudentsGridControl}"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding StudentsCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudent}">
                    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                        <dxg:GridColumn Width="200" HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center" Binding="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            <dxg:GridColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Student Name" Style="{StaticResource BaseColumnHeaderStyle}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </dxg:GridColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <dxg:GridColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="Control">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#22322"/>
                                </Style>
                            </dxg:GridColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        </dxg:GridColumn>
                        <dxg:GridColumn Width="50" HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center" 
Binding= // This is the ID Column     
                       <dxg:GridColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="ID" Style="{StaticResource BaseColumnHeaderStyle}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </dxg:GridColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <dxg:GridColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="Control">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#123453"/>
                                </Style>
                            </dxg:GridColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        </dxg:GridColumn>
                        <dxg:GridColumn Width="230" HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center" Binding="{Binding FavoriteSubject, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            <dxg:GridColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Favorite Subject" Style="{StaticResource BaseColumnHeaderStyle}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </dxg:GridColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <dxg:GridColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="Control">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#52648F"/>
                                </Style>
                            </dxg:GridColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        </dxg:GridColumn>
                        <dxg:GridColumn Width="50" HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center" Binding="{Binding GPA, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            <dxg:GridColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="GPA"Style="{StaticResource BaseColumnHeaderStyle}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </dxg:GridColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <dxg:GridColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="Control">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#52658F"/>
                                </Style>
                            </dxg:GridColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        </dxg:GridColumn>
                    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                    <dxg:GridControl.View>
                        <dxg:TableView Style="{StaticResource StudensTable}"/>
                    </dxg:GridControl.View>
                   </dxg:GridControl>
```

Comment: What do you hope to do with the ID field? Since it isn't tied to Students, the ID field could be different every time a Student is deleted or added to the list. Do you in fact, *want* it to be tied to the students?

Comment: It is basically just for reference. It is used in a more visual control and I rather use the ID rather than the name for brevity. The reason I don't want to persist this property to the Student is because items cannot be deleted from the collection in this particular view and I would like for them to be reset when this particular Window is re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

As one of solutions you can use `MultiBinding` for it and find an index or what ever you want in a `MultiValueConverter`:

```
public class MValConv : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            try
            {
                if(values[0] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue || values[1] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
                return -1;
                if (values.Length == 2 && values[0] is ObservableCollection<Student> ocol && values[1] is Student st)
                {
                    return (ocol.IndexOf(st) + 1).ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }            
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("one way only");
        }
    }

<Window.Resources>
    <local:MValConv x:Key="MValCnv"/>
</Window.Resources>

<dxg:GridColumn.Binding>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MValCnv}">
        <Binding Path="DataContext.StudentsCollection" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=dxg:GridControl}"/>
        <Binding/>
    </MultiBinding>
</dxg:GridColumn.Binding>
```

Hmm, if it is bug by DevExpress, then you could may be try to use regular binding + ValueConverter with a dependency property for the collection.

Comment: I see, but the problem is, values[] comes up as DependencyProperty.UnsetValue

Comment: Have you tried without the binding for collection, do you become a Student with only `<Binding/>`

Comment: I see DevExpress has a "feature": _This behavior is a known limitation of version 13.2. It is impossible to bind a column to an external source other than RowData.Row.PropertyName or RowData.Data.PropertyName (or just PropertyName without a prefix)._ [Multibinding giving a DependencyProperty.UnsetValue](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T308912/multibinding-giving-a-dependencyproperty-unsetvalue-for-value-connected-to-a-property-of)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a StudentViewModel for your Student class, don't forget to change your `StudentsCollection` to be an `ObservableCollection<StudentViewModel>`. ViewModels are used to avoid binding Models directly to the View, it also allows you to declare other properties without affecting your Model, like an `ID` in this case.

Let's pretend this is your Student class :

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FavoriteSubject { get; set; }
    public string GPA { get; set; }
}
```

Your StudentViewModel could be something like this :

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
    private Student _student;

    public StudentViewModel(Student student, int id)
    {
        _student = student;
        ID = id;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _student.Name; }
        set { _student.Name = value; }
    }

    public string FavoriteSubject
    {
        get { return _student.FavoriteSubject; }
        set { _student.FavoriteSubject = value; }
    }

    public string GPA
    {
        get { return _student.GPA; }
        set { _student.GPA = value; }
    }
}
```